# add a single line of code to a function of a class in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example

```
class abcd(base_class):
    def test1(self,list_of_ids):
        ###some other statements
        return list_of_ids
```

this is the base class.. I cant edit that. So I need to inherit the class and need to add a line `list(set(list_of_ids))` in the test1(). How can I do this?

Comment: And what is your problem then? What did you try, what happened and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: You have to be more precise. What is the problem? Why don't you add the line?

Comment: Are you doing this in the interactive interpreter?

Comment: This class abcd() is a base class and i cant edit it.. i have to create another py file and inherit that class abcd()

Comment: @AnomA: Better edit the question to include that information.

Comment: Also, I don't think you really want to "add a line `list(set(list_of_ids))`" because that line would not do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, create a sub-class, call the method of the parent class, and modify the output:

```
class Modifiedabcd(abcd):
    def test1(self, list_of_ids):
        ###some other statements
        temp = super(Modifiedabcd, self).test1(list_of_ids)
        return list(set(temp))
```